# Hive tables join with count

Tags: join, hive, inner-join, hiveql

Assume there are two tables, `user` and `comments`. below are the fields in each of the tables,

**user**:

```
userid
username
```

**Comments**:

```
commentID
commentDescription
userid
```

write a query to find users who have more than 2 comments

**o/p file**:

```
userid
username
commentDescription
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select u.userid,
       u.username,
       c.commentDescription 
  from user u
       inner join (select c.userid, c.commentDescription, 
                          count(*) over(partition by userid) cnt
                     from comments c
                  ) c 
        on u.userid=c.userid and c.cnt>2;
```